# Ruby Premailer Gem: Ignore Feature Doesn't Always Work

Tags: ruby, premailer

I'm using the [premailer 1.8.4](https://github.com/premailer/premailer) gem and have a Perl / CGI script that calls premailer.rb.

Premailer ignores styles wrapped in the data-premailer="ignore" style tag -

For example: test.html

```
<style data-premailer="ignore">
/* this is a test */
</style>
```

For testing, I have the following in premailer-test.rb.  It is run against test.html.

```
html = 'test.html'
premailer = Premailer.new(html, :warn_level => Premailer::Warnings::SAFE, :remove_comments => true)
puts premailer.to_inline_css
```

On execution, it streams the processed test.html file to my screen with the `data-premailer="ignore"` styles intact.

However, when I call premailer.rb,

```
input_url = ARGV[0]

premailer = Premailer.new(input_url, :warn_level => Premailer::Warnings::NONE)

# Write the HTML output
fout = File.open(input_url, "w")
fout.puts premailer.to_inline_css
fout.close

# Output any CSS warnings
premailer.warnings.each do |w|
  puts "#{w[:message]} (#{w[:level]}) may not render properly in #{w[:clients]}"
end
```

from within the cgi program (e.g. ruby premailer.rb msgid.html), the file saved has the `data-premailer="ignore"` styles stripped out.

I would like the `data-premailer="ignore"` styles to remain. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Running this directly without going through a cgi program I can't reproduce this, both examples have the same output. Maybe try the [premailer binary](https://github.com/premailer/premailer/blob/master/lib/premailer/executor.rb)?

Comment: Thanks, It looks like the CGI program, which includes a TinyMCE editor - is responsible for stripping the ignore tags (and their contents) out even before the premailer is called.